# Tap imageView to view Fullscreen image

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimageview

I have a uiimageview in my detail view, and I want to make it so that when I tap on the image, it opens the image full screen. However, my code below doesn't seem to be working. Any idea what I seem to be doing wrong?

**FullViewController.h**

```
@interface FullArticleViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>


    {
        IBOutlet UITapGestureRecognizer *tap;
        IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
        IBOutlet UILabel *firstnameLabel;
        IBOutlet UILabel *bodyLabel;
        IBOutlet UILabel *descriptionLabel;


        BOOL isFullScreen;
        CGRect prevFrame;        
    }
```

**FullViewController.m**

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

           if ([[articleDetail objectForKey:@"ytID"] isEqualToString:@"none"]) {

           featureImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

           NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image/%@",cellImageLink];

           [self.featureImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];

           [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];

           featureImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

           [scroller bringSubviewToFront:featureImage];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapgesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imgToFullScreen)];
        [tapgesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

        [featureImage addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    }

    - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch;
    {
        BOOL shouldReceiveTouch = YES;

        if (gestureRecognizer == tap) {
            shouldReceiveTouch = (touch.view == featureImage);
        }
        return shouldReceiveTouch;
    }

    -(void)imgToFullScreen{
        if (!isFullScreen) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
                //save previous frame
                prevFrame = featureImage.frame;
                [featureImage setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
            }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                isFullScreen = true;
            }];
            return;
        } else {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
                [featureImage setFrame:prevFrame];
            }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                isFullScreen = false;
            }];
            return;
        }
    }
```

**Edit: See code updated above, and hierarchy below**

[image]

Comment: @rdelmar Yep, I did.

Comment: What result are you getting with this code? Does it do nothing?

Comment: @rdelmar Correct; it just does nothing.

Comment: It might be helpful to post an image of your view hierarchy from the scene list.

Comment: So, actually, your image view is at the bottom of the hierarchy, not the top (visually, I'm talking about -- the bottom most view in the list is the top most in z order). That being said, bringing it to the front should have worked. Are you sure your scroller IBOutlet is set?  Also, you could try dragging the image view to the bottom of the list to change it's z-order.

Comment: @rdelmar Wow that definitely threw me for a loop; lol, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `viewDidLoad:` method:

```
[featureImage setUserInteractionEnables:YES];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapgesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imgToFullScreen)];
[tapgesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[featureImage addGestureRecognizer:tapgesture];
```

Comment: This half works; lol. When I add this code to viewDidLoad and run the app, tapping on the imageview makes the image go full screen, however it goes fullscreen behind all of the view's text (so it looks like it just sets the tapped image as a background). Also: The image is horizontal, and it's stretching it out vertically. How can I make it so that the image goes full screen on top of all the content?

Comment: Use `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:featureImage];` before animating it to full screen.

Comment: Well obviously your image view has the wrong hierarchy in your controllers view. You need to bring it to the top. Check out some coding fundamental guides for this.

Comment: That's the frustrating part; my imageview IS at the top of the hierarchy (embedded in the view, obviously)...

Comment: This may not be the neatest way but you could add the imageview to the app delegates window when going in full screen and back to your controllers view when going back.

Comment: I just changed that line to: [scroller bringSubviewToFront:featureImage]; As I realized everything was embedded in my scrollView. That said, still no dice. See edits & hierarchy above :)

Comment: UGH nevermind... I've just been informed that my imageview was really at the bottom afterall... Nice one, Brittany. Lol. Thank you! :)